# Composite of Automated Expansion Entity in Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

In Dialogflow for my Google Action, I have this automated expansion entity, called food, trained with some types of food included bananas and onions.

Then I have a composite entity called thing-to-buy structured like this:
@sys.number:number @food:food @sys.date:date

My intent has just one training phrase:
'four bananas tomorrow' auto-detected by dialogflow as thing-to-buy entity

In the simulator, when I say 'four bananas tommorrow' it obviously works well, getting the thing-to-buy as {date: 2019-02-26T12:00:00+01:00, food: bananas, number: 4}

It works also when I say another food present in the training phrases of the entity 'food', like 'onions'
'100 onions today' ->   {"date":"2019-02-25T12:00:00+01:00","number":100,"food":"onions"}

But when I try with a food that's not present in the 'food' training phrases, it doesen't recognize it as a new one:
'4 carrots tomorrow' -> {}

Why is it so? 
Is there a way I can achieve my goal of having my big 'thing-to-buy' entity?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you don't have enough data to bot to be trained although the auto expansion is on. You will have to add more utterances/entity values and keep on trying for the bot to be trained.